# Using Espeak with os in python

Tags: python, operating-system, espeak

When I open up my command prompt, i am able to type espeak and then the text i want to be said, however when i try to do this through my python code using os it says

> `'espeak' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.`

```
import os
text = "Apples"
os.system('espeak "{}"'.format(text))
```

I've tinkered with the code a fair amount but there is not much to tinker

Answer (score 1):

try `/usr/bin/espeak` instead of `espeak`.
That works for my machine.

In order to be sure it works for your host I suggest you open a console and type

```
type espeak
```

This will output the absolute path of espeak. Copy that one into your system command